# Google app engine bulkloader environment variables

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I rely on python's `os.environ` to work out what configs my application should use (such as different API keys for different hosts).

It seems that bulkloader doesn't have access to these variables, is there anyway I can tell what the current version of my application or the current host is when bulkloader is running?

Usually I do this in my `config_helper`:

```
env = os.environ[ 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID' ].split( '.' )[ 0 ]
```

And bulkloader has reported a KeyError regarding `CURRENT_VERSION_ID`, so I used this:

```
if os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST'): 
    host = os.environ['HTTP_HOST'] 
else: 
    host = os.environ['SERVER_NAME']
if host is not None:
    if host.find( 'locahost' ):
        env = 'local'

    elif host.find( 'prod-server' ):
        env = 'prod'

    elif host.find( 'dev-server' ):
        env = 'dev'

    elif host.find( 'stage-server' ):
        env = 'stage'

    os.environ[ 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID' ] = env + '.1'
```

However bulkloader complains that `SERVER_NAME` is an invalid object meaning that it also can't find `HTTP_HOST`.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables like HTTP_HOST and CURRENT_VERSION_ID are only available when your app is running as a web application.

Probably you can just pass the variables with env command as follows:

```
$ env CURRENT_VERSION_ID=local.1 bulkloader ....
```